sql filter from another table
Hello everyone i am developing a website that listing and filtering products.
My problem is products table is have 40000 row and product_details have 2.1 million row.
I want to filter products table with product_details table
my code is
$sliced = array_values(array_slice($req_val, 3));
    
        $products = Products::where('status', 1)
            ->where('s_part', $req_val[0])
            ->where('main_category', $req_val[1])
            ->where('sub_category', $req_val[2])
            ->join('product_details', 'products.sapcode', '=', 'product_details.sapcode')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($sliced, $keys) {
                foreach ($sliced as $index => $value) {
                    $key = $keys[$index];
                    $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($value, $key) {
                        $query->where('product_details.value', $value)
                            ->where('product_details.name', $key);
                    });
                }
            })
            ->get('products.sapcode');
        
        $products = $products->map(function($item){
            return $item->sapcode;
        });
    
        $counts = array_count_values($products->toArray());
    
        $threshold = count($sliced);
    
        $filtered = array_filter($counts, function($count) use ($threshold) {
            return $count >= $threshold;
        });
    
        $result = array_keys($filtered);
    
        $products = Products::whereIn('products.sapcode', $result)->get();
        return response()->json($products);

Products model connected to products table
Product_details is connected to product_details
How to connect and filter this two table. What is the best way to do it.

Anything not working with a JOIN? Which part are you struggling with?

I was working on this situation and solve it.
$filteredProducts = ProductS::select('products.sapcode', 'products.status', 'products.TR', 'products.EN', 'products.module')
            ->join('product_details', 'products.sapcode', '=', 'product_details.sapcode')
            ->where('products.status', 1)
            ->where('products.s_part', $req_val[0])
            ->where('products.main_category', $req_val[1])
            ->where('products.sub_category', $req_val[2])
            ->where(function ($query) use ($sliced, $keys) {
                foreach ($sliced as $index => $value) {
                    $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($keys, $value, $index) {
                        $query->where('product_details.name', $keys[$index])
                            ->where('product_details.value', $value);
                    });
                }
            })
            ->groupBy('products.sapcode', 'products.status', 'products.TR', 'products.EN', 'products.module')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) >= '.count($sliced));

havingRaw is check for sapcode childs for unique filtered product.

One way to do it is how you are doing it know: An eloquent builder with a join.
I think an easier to read solution would be defining the relations in your models. I guess you have 1:M or N:M relations here, so use hasMany, belongsToMany/belongstoOne, then you can use whereHas like this:
->wehereHas('productDetails', function(Builder $query) {
    // here you filter by product details
    $query->where('column', $value);
}


$filteredProducts = Products::where('status', 1)
->where('s_part', $req_val[0])
->where('main_category', $req_val[1])
->where('sub_category', $req_val[2])
->whereHas('details', function ($query) use ($sliced, $keys) {
foreach ($sliced as $index => $value) {
$key = $keys[$index];
$query->where('value', $value)
->where('name', $key);
}
})
->get();
I tried this but its not working

What is the error you are receiving?

I had no error just not work like excepted

normally it should be 67 product but returns 0

As I see you also changed your query in a way that orWhere is not present anymore. If you know your expected results, then you can check calling toSql() helper on you builder. That will log out how you builder converts into SQL, soyou can tell which query is correct for your case.
